# R question about plotting probability/density histogram the right way

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I have a following matrix [500,2], so we have 500 rows and 2 columns, the left one gives us the index of X observations, and the right one gives the probability with which this X comes true, so - a typical probability density relationship.

So, my question is, how to plot the histogram the right way, so that the x-axis is the x-index, and the y-axis is the density(0.01-1.00). The bandwidth of the estimator is 0.33.

Thanks in advance!

the end of the whole data looks like this: just for a little orientation

```
[490,]  2.338260830 0.04858685
[491,]  2.347839477 0.04797310
[492,]  2.357418125 0.04736149
[493,]  2.366996772 0.04675206
[494,]  2.376575419 0.04614482
[495,]  2.386154067 0.04553980
[496,]  2.395732714 0.04493702
[497,]  2.405311361 0.04433653
[498,]  2.414890008 0.04373835
[499,]  2.424468656 0.04314252
[500,]  2.434047303 0.04254907
```

@everyone,
yes, I have made the estimation before, so.. the bandwith is what I mentioned, the data is ordered from low to high values, so respecively the probability at the beginning is 0,22, at the peak about 0,48, at the end 0,15.

The line with the density is plotted like a charm but I have to do in addition is to plot a histogram! So, how I can do this, ordering the blocks properly(ho the data to be splitted in boxes etc..)

Any suggestions?

Here is a part of the data AFTER the estimation, all values are discrete, so I assume histogram can be created.., hopefully.

```
[491,] 4.956164 0.2618131
[492,] 4.963014 0.2608723
[493,] 4.969863 0.2599309
[494,] 4.976712 0.2589889
[495,] 4.983562 0.2580464
[496,] 4.990411 0.2571034
[497,] 4.997260 0.2561599
[498,] 5.004110 0.2552159
[499,] 5.010959 0.2542716
[500,] 5.017808 0.2533268
[501,] 5.024658 0.2523817
```

Best regards,
appreciate the fast responses!(bow)

What will do the job is to create a histogram just for the indexes, grouping them in a way x25/x50 each, for instance...and compute the average probability for each 25 or 50/100/150/200/250 etc as boxes..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rows are in order from lowest to highest value of x, as they appear to be, you can use the default plot command, the only change you need is the type:

```
plot(your.data, type = 'l')
```

EDIT:

Ok, I'm not sure this is better than the density plot, but it can be done:

```
x = dnorm(seq(-1, 1, length = 500))
x.bins = rep(1:50, each = 10)
bars = aggregate(x, by = list(x.bins), FUN = sum)[,2]
barplot(bars)
```

In your case, replace x with the probabilities from the second column of your matrix.

EDIT2:

On second thought, this only makes sense if your 500 rows represent discrete events. If they are instead points along a continuous distribution function adding them together as I have done is incorrect. Mathematically I don't think you can produce the binned probability for a range using only a few points from within that range.

Comment: @Tyler, this worked like a charm, many thanks, the one thing I still need to do is to put both columns of the data in a histogram together, x-axis=observations, y-axis=probabilities/density...

Comment: Hi again, to be more correct, I will post the values after the estimation, those in the first post are just aken form a normal distribution, so now I will post the estimated ones, which are completely discrete. will edit my question in 2 mins.

Comment: Did you try my solution? It should do just what you asked for: it calculates the total probability for each group of 10 rows, and plots them in a 'histogram'. If you want to change the bin size, you need to modify x.bins. As written it will produce 50 groups of 10. You can replace 50 and 10 with any numbers you like, so long as their product is 500 (i.e., 1:20, each = 25; 1:100, each = 5).

Comment: the third row gives an error:
Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  arguments must have same length
probably I cannot define it properly?

Comment: I have done it, I got the bars now, they look just like a "fat" Gassian curve. The "middle" observation are with the highest probability, but one thing is wrong, that y axis is 1-6, the x axis has no name...

Comment: Labeling axes is covered in great detail in the R help manuals. As for the Y range, well... This is definitely not a 'typical probability density function', as by definition such a function for discrete events sums to 1. Just the last eleven values in your sample data sum to more than 2.5, so I have no idea what you're actually doing.

Comment: Well, the histogramm is plotted, the x and y axes aren't named. The last thing is just to specify the x-axis to be dividided in the same intervals as the histogram blocks(speak 1-50/50-100/100-150/150-200..), as to specify 0,1,0,2,0,3...-1,0 restriction for the y-axis.. will search the internet and write again if I can't find a solution.

Best regards and big THANKS for the help!!!!

Comment: Your welcome! A few notes on etiquette: If you find an answer helpful, it's customary around here to upvote it - click on the up-arrow above the number for the post. You can also indicate the best answer for your question by clicking on the checkmark beside that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming M is the matrix.  wouldn't this just be :

```
plot(x=M[ , 1], y = M[ , 2] )
```

You have already done the density estimation since this is not the original data.